Old polite form of 形容詞
In multiple sources now, I've heard that like 100 or so years ago now, there 形容詞 had their own polite form that didn't use 〜です.
So instead of saying, 熱いです or 暑かったです, a different form was used to show politeness. However, I seem unable to find what this old polite form.
Is it related to the old honorific お〜形容詞〜ございます, still found in おはようございます?

Do these answer your question? Conjugating present and past negative i-adjectives / ～うございます - keigo い-adjectives
